# Discord.js get motd

Tags: javascript, discord.js, minecraft

How do I get a MOTD of a Minecraftserver and put it into a embed?
If I type /status in. The Discord-Bot should reply the motd of the server replaysucht.de:255655 in a embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const serverInfo = require('minecraft-server-util');

let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Server Information")
    .setTimestamp()

    serverInfo.status('replaysucht.de') //default port: 25565
    .then((response) => {
      embed
        .setDescription(response.description.descriptionText)
        message.channel.send(embed)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
    });
```

For this example you need `minecraft-server-util` so make sure you've installed and defined it.

So in the code we create an embed `embed`. You can change the embed look to what you want, this was just an example. With `serverInfo.status('replaysucht.de')` we fetch all the information you need, for your problem. We get the MOTD from response by using `.then` after we fetched the information. The exact MOTD is stored in `response.description.descriptionText`. If the bot can fetch that without any problems, the embed gets sent in the channel, otherwise it will throw an error.

As the most Minecraft Servers have special and animated characters in their MOTD's it will be displayed like:

```
§f§f §7•§8● §eReplaySucht §8✕ §7we code for you §4:heart: §8✕ §e1§8.§e8 §8●§7•
§4Info §8» §cKurze Wartungsarbeiten!
```

inside the embed description.

Comment: Edit Queue is full but if you want to know how to strip the special characters, you can do it like this: https://gist.github.com/LiamTownsley/225344449f0fb1ed5b865a88b7a5e6e4

Answer (score 0):

Since minecraft-server-util and that version of discord.js is deprecated, here's a working way:

```js
import mc from "minecraftstatuspinger"

let result = await mc.lookup({ host: "mc.hypixel.net" })

let motdEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle("mc.hypixel.net")
    .setDescription(result.status.description.text)

interaction.reply({embeds: [motdEmbed]})
```

For this, you need the [MinecraftStatusPinger](https://github.com/woodendoors7/MinecraftStatusPinger) library.

#### Step 1: Import the Library

Import the library. You have to import it in different ways based on if your project is a module or commonjs.

```js
import mc from "minecraftstatuspinger"
```

Tip: You need your NodeJS project to be a module in order to use "import".

#### Step 2: Ping the server.

Call the .lookup function with the wanted options. Make sure the parent function is asynchronous (`async`), otherwise you'll have to use `.then`.

```js
let status = await mc.lookup({ host: "mc.hypixel.net" })
```

If your server is on a different port than the default 25565, you need to add a port option. [All the options are here](https://github.com/woodendoors7/MinecraftStatusPinger#user-content-lookupoptions)

#### Step 3: Make the embed

```js
let motdEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle("mc.hypixel.net")
    .setDescription(result.status.description.text)
```

#### Step 4: Send it!

Depending on if you're replying to a slash command, or a message, use either of these:

```js
// If it's an interaction
interaction.reply({embeds: [motdEmbed]})
//If it's a message
message.channel.send({embeds: [motdEmbed]})
```